# How to pass data of a JavaScript variable to another php page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have two pages: **test.php** and **backend.php**.

**test.php** has three images which when clicked takes the user to **backend.php**. I want the src of the image clicked to be displayed on **backend.php**. I am trying to achieve this task via JavaScript and Ajax but the src of the image doesn't appear on **backend.php**. Code for the same are given below:

**test.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js">
        </script>

        <script>
            function clickIt(data){
                $.ajax({
                           url: 'backend.php',
                           data: {"imgsrc":data},
                           type: 'post',
                           success:function(res){
                              alert(res.message);
                           }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="backend.php">
            <img onclick="clickIt(this.src)" src="img1.jpg"/>
        </a>
        <a href="backend.php">
            <img onclick="changeIt(this.src)" src="img2.jpg"/>
        </a>
        <a href="backend.php">
            <img onclick="changeIt(this.src)" src="img3.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**backend.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<?php
    echo $_POST['imgsrc'];
    echo '<a href="test.php">Back</a>';
?>
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing `alert(res.message)`? Where is `message` supposed to come from? Did you try `alert(res)`? Or better: `console.log(res)`.

Comment: if you want page to redirect to backend.php after image clicck..and display image there..in that case dont use ajax..use window.location.href for redirection and also pass image source along with url...otherwise you can also see image src in console..

Comment: Felix, `alert(res.message)` is only there to display a success message. But currently it displays undefined. No, I haven't tried them.

Comment: Dhara, can you please walk me through a running code?

Comment: @rajarshi check..i have posted answer below

Comment: Yes, `res.message` is `undefined` because `res` is a string that contains the data you are `echo`ing in PHP. `res` itself contains the output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

HTML:

```
<body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img onclick="clickIt(this.src)" src="img1.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img onclick="changeIt(this.src)" src="img2.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img onclick="changeIt(this.src)" src="img3.jpg"/>
    </a>
</body>
```

Jquery:

```
function clickIt(data){
    window.location.href = 'backend.php?imgsrc='+data; // redirect to backend.php
}
```

In backend.php

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['imgsrc']; // use $_GET
    echo '<a href="test.php">Back</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Dhara, this suits my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click event of  tag is not firing because   tag takes the
   page to backend page before  tag click event gets fired. You can resolve this problem simply by removing the  tag from each line.
2. You cannot access ajax response as res.message as you haven't echo the response in json format. You can access response simply from res variable
3. Also change the function name to changeIt to clickIt as you have defined function has clickIt

// use only res
success:function(res)
{
    alert(res);

}

```
<img onclick="clickIt(this.src)" src="img1.jpg"/>
<img onclick="clikcIt(this.src)" src="img2.jpg"/>
<img onclick="clickIt(this.src)" src="img3.jpg"/>
```